# How to mount shared folder between server and docker container?

Tags: docker, architecture, mount, nfs

I need to setup a shared folder between a remote server A (server)(ubuntu) and a list of docker containers B, C, D (clients)(debian). I'm using Rancher to manage these containers, and they can move on different hosts, so I don't want to share any volume with the docker host. A must receive and delete files and must be able to communicate these changes to B, C, D, and it's the same for the inverse relation.
My containers are accessible through load balancer with haproxy redirection.

I'm struggling since several days to find a solution to properly share these folders, but I'm never did that before. I tried to use the nfs-driver in Rancher, I was never able to load anything with it ; and I also try to directly mount a Network File System (NFS) also without success: the two servers are not able to communicate between them, and when I try to mount the folder, nothing is happening. I saw it's the server side which is refusing the connection (but ping is working) so probably a problem of password or maybe of mapping. I read NFS was not designed to share folders on cloud, but all the servers are in the same area at my provider with the possibility to put them in a private Network, so I supposed it could work.

Do you it's possible to use NFS in this case ? If yes do you have any leads on the configuration for the docker clients (specially on the domain name, because I can't set an ip for them). Or if not, which other solution I can use ?

A help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code to show?
what you are looking for are docker volumes
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

e.g. the -v switch

`docker run -itd -v "mylocalfolder":"myContainerFolder" container:name sh`

Comment: Hi Zee303
I followed some guides for NFS: https://www.stephenrlang.com/2016/01/setup-nfsv4-on-ubuntu-or-debian/
I'm stuck at the mount step

Are you sure for volumes ? I don't see how I can use them. Server A doesn't host any docker container, it's a separate system which need to send/receive files from B C D containers
So how to mount data from remote server directly inside containers ? They are build locally with docker-compose, and I upload the image on Rancher
When I tested rancher-nfs, it never succeed to create a volume. I don't understand why, I had no access to console logs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your solution will require a combination of using Docker volume configuration, as described in the first answer, along with NFS or similar remote mounting technologies.  Using Docker volume mounting, you can map a host filesystem location to a filesystem location in the container.  You'll have to figure out how to map that host filesystem location to a filesystem on a different host, using NFS.